# Allow program priveledges to change PC Name from any account on startup?

Tags: c, windows, startup, uac, impersonation

I'm writing a basic program that on start-up sends the PC's active NIC to the server and changes the PC's host name appropriately. The process is outlined below.

**Program Execution Process:**

1. Started automatically by any account
2. Collects active NIC Address
3. Sends NIC Address to Server
4. Receives assigned PC host-name
5. Compares current and assigned host-names
6. *Changes Host-name if necessary*

I have the program performing steps 1-5 perfectly as designed. It's able to collect the active NIC address, prepare the packet for the server and receive the response. The issue is when the program reaches step 6. When on Windows XP the program changes the host-name without issues if only signed in as an administrator. On Windows Vista, 7 and 8 the program is unable to change the computers host-name (Due to requiring UAC Elevation) or if signed into a user account that does not have Administrator privileges it lacks the necessary permissions.

Upon adding an Application manifest to the program to signal users and Windows that the program requires administrator rights the program fails to launch as Windows Vista and above wont start programs requiring administrator rights on start-up.

After the previous manifest modification I created a sepereate user account on the machine that is an administrator so that the program can Impersonate the administrator account and have full access to the computer without requiring the active user to be an admin. Again on Windows XP it worked flawlessly. When on Windows 7 the program would throw a "Permission Denied" message. I have tried both Process.Start as well as C Sharp impersonation with the advapi32.dll and userenv.dll as shown below.

What is the best method to allow a program privileges to change PC Name from any account on start-up?

**process.start Method**

```
ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
myProcess.UserName = username;
myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
myProcess.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(myProcess);
```

**Impersonation Method**

```
static void Imp()
        {
            WindowsImpersonationContext m_ImpersonationContext = null;
            WindowsIdentity m_ImpersonatedUser;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
            const int SecurityImpersonation = 2;
            const int TokenType = 1;
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

            try
            {
                if (RevertToSelf())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: " +
                                      WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                    String userName = "sfadmin";
                    //IntPtr password = GetPassword();

                    if (LogonUser(userName, Environment.MachineName,
                                  "d31ux3", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                                  LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
                    {
                        if (DuplicateToken(token, SecurityImpersonation, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                            m_ImpersonatedUser = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                            using (m_ImpersonationContext = m_ImpersonatedUser.Impersonate())
                            {
                                if (m_ImpersonationContext != null)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("After Impersonation succeeded: " +
                                        Environment.NewLine +
                                        "User Name: " +
                                        WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(
                                           TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed).Name +
                                        Environment.NewLine +
                                        "SID: " +
                                        WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(
                                           TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed).User.Value);

                                    #region LoadUserProfile
                                    // Load user profile
                                    ProfileInfo profileInfo = new ProfileInfo();
                                    profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
                                    profileInfo.lpUserName = userName;
                                    profileInfo.dwFlags = 1;
                                    Boolean loadSuccess =
                                            LoadUserProfile(tokenDuplicate, ref profileInfo);

                                    if (!loadSuccess)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("LoadUserProfile() failed with error code: " +
                                                          Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                                    }

                                    if (profileInfo.hProfile == IntPtr.Zero)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(
                                            "LoadUserProfile() failed - HKCU handle " +
                                            "was not loaded. Error code: " +
                                            Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                                    }
                                    #endregion

                                    CloseHandle(token);
                                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);

                                    // Do tasks after impersonating successfully
                                    //AccessFileSystem();

                                    RunAs("SolarFrost.exe", "sfadmin", "d31ux3");


                                    // Access HKCU after loading user's profile
                                    //AccessHkcuRegistry(profileInfo.hProfile);

                                    // Unload user profile
                                    // MSDN remarks
                                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762282(VS.85).aspx
                                    // Before calling UnloadUserProfile you should
                                    // ensure that all handles to keys that you have opened in the
                                    // user's registry hive are closed. If you do not
                                    // close all open registry handles, the user's profile fails
                                    // to unload. For more information, see Registry Key
                                    // Security and Access Rights and Registry Hives.
                                    UnloadUserProfile(tokenDuplicate, profileInfo.hProfile);

                                    // Undo impersonation
                                    m_ImpersonationContext.Undo();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("DuplicateToken() failed with error code: " +
                                              Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt", Ex.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(token);
                if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);

                Console.WriteLine("After finished impersonation: " +
                                  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a task using the [Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in Windows. Set the task to run at startup whether someone has been logged in or not. Also make sure that the task runs at [highest privilege](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (checkbox). This should solve your problem.

Comment: I was under the impression that Task Scheduler was for users to schedule tasks for their workstations. Considering that I plan to put this program online upon completion for others to use does a program listed in Task Scheduler appear less professional than a program listed in ms-config >> Start-up (or Windows 8 Task Manager >> Start-up) ?

Comment: I originally coded this program as a Windows service, however since I plan to enable to program to install the .NET framework as well later (requiring desktop interaction) I believe that kills my previous service idea as well.

Comment: @CoderWalker I don't see any difference in "professionalism" between the two variants. Have you ever looked what's scheduled on your System? - On min for example, even Adobe schedules it's updates through this mechanism. I also don't see a reason to Keep this program hanging around in the system as a Service for it only does something useful on system start...